# I created a logo and part of the logo used transparency and then put a black background, part of the logo disappears..can someone help me pls

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

[image]

So, I created a logo and part of the logo used transparency and then put a black background, part of the logo disappears..

The circles outside, i put transparency > multiply, then a put black background disapears.

...so can you help me please?

Comment: How would you expect a transparent object to appear over black? You should remove all transparency from the logo.

Answer (score 2):

The issues is with your choice of blend modes.

You said the transparency of the blues in your logo is set to multiply, which has created the darker circle overlaps in your design.

Multiply will blend the colour with the base colour. In this case it will blend the black with the blue. Multiply will produce darker colours and if you are multiplying with black, well, you can't go much darker! Which is why you can't see it.

Adobe has a concise page on the blend modes here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transparency-blending-modes.html

I would just flatten the transparency of the design. That would take the colours you have and turn them into solid colour values. This should fix the issue.

Bear in mind, this will outline the stroke and divide it. So do this after you have settled on your final widths of your stroke or keep a copy to the side in case you want to go back and edit it again.